# Using grid.newpage to create ggplot map with inset map

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgdal, r-raster, r-sp

Following a very useful example [here](http://r-nold.blogspot.com/2014/06/creating-inset-map-with-ggplot2.html). I have cobbled together code for a map created in ggplot with an inset.

```
# Clear WD
rm(list=ls())

library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(gridExtra)

# Download the Level 0 Map for Inset
ind0 <- getData("GADM", country="IDN", level=0) 
    # Decrease Resolution of the National Map for the Inset
    ind01<- gSimplify(ind0, tol=.1)

# Download level 2 Map 
ind2 <- getData("GADM", country="IDN", level=2) # ucdavis site

jawa  <- (ind2[grep(x=ind2$NAME_1, pattern="Jawa"),]) # subset to island of Jawa

# Extent rectangle for inset map
pol <- data.frame(xmin=114,xmax=119, ymin=-6.5 ,ymax=-5)

batang <- jawa[which(jawa@data$NAME_2=="Batang"),]
    munnames <- coordinates(batang) # get center coordinates of 
    munnames <- data.frame(munnames) # convert matrix format munnames object to data.frame
    munnames$label <- batang@data$NAME_2


# Main Map
p1 <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=jawa, aes(long+0.008,lat-0.005, group=group), fill="#9ecae1") + coord_equal()+theme_bw() + xlab("")+ylab("") +  theme(axis.text.y =element_text(angle = 90, hjust=0.5)) + geom_polygon(data=batang, aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="coral1") + geom_text(data=munnames, aes(x=X1, y=X2+.3,label=label), size=3, colour="grey20", family="Times") + guides(fill=FALSE) + annotate("text", x=108.5, y=-5.5, label="Island of Java", family="Times") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(104, 116, 2), labels=c(paste(seq(104, 116, 2),"°E", sep=""))) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-9, -5, 1), labels=c(paste(seq(-9, -5, 1),"°N", sep="")))

#Inset
p2 <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=ind0, aes(long,lat,group=group), fill="#9ecae1") + coord_equal() + theme_bw() + labs(x=NULL,y=NULL) + geom_rect(data = pol, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha=0, colour="red", size = 1, linetype=1) + theme(axis.text.x =element_blank(),axis.text.y= element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(),axis.title.x =element_blank(), axis.title.y= element_blank())
```

Here is where I encounter a problem. Using grid.newpage and viewport my computer stalls when it goes to print the inset. What am I doing wrong? You will notice that I have even take efforts to decrease the resolution of the national shape file that goes into the inset.

```
png(file="cj3.png",w=1800,h=1800, res=300, bg = "transparent")
grid.newpage()
    v1<-viewport(width = 1, height = 1, x = 0.5, y = 0.5) #plot area for the main map
    v2<-viewport(width = 0.3, height = 0.3, x = 0.80, y = 0.80) #plot area for the inset map
    print(p1,vp=v1) 
    print(p2,vp=v2)
dev.off()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where does the `IDN_adm2.rds` come from

Comment: there are these things… called "newlines"…

Comment: Scott, that line was extra and I have removed it. Sorry. The code to download the sp files loads all the data necessary.

Comment: Works for me, although the rectangle in the insert does not enclose Java. Try drawing p2 on its own. I do need to wait 5 or 6 seconds for p2 to draw.

Comment: Thanks, Sandy. So bizarre. My computer just spin and spins whenever I print p2.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is [image: *this* image] look at your first chunk where you are simplifying the source:

```
ind01<- gSimplify(ind0, tol=.1)
```

Now, look at the p2 chunk

```
p2 <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=ind0, ...
```

where it uses the **un**simplified version, **ind0** instead of **ind01**. My old Mac Air hung on the original but finished in less than a minute after correcting the data argument in p2.